connect_to localhost error while testing remote SSH connection with netcat from bash script
I'm writing a bash script that needs to maintain a SSH connection (SSH tunnel) to a remote host alive. I am checking whether connection on the remote IP exists with netcat -z, and if it doesn't, then I start it, and the loop goes on.
This is my script:
#!/bin/bash
RIP="A.B.C.D"
RPORT=8000
CHK_CONN="nc -z $RIP $RPORT"

while true
do
  $CHK_CONN
  alive=$?
  if [ $alive -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "No SSH tunnel to $RIP:$RPORT. Starting..."
    ssh -N -R $RIP:$RPORT:127.0.0.1:8000 <usr>@$RIP -i '/path/to/key' -o 'BatchMode yes' -o 'ServerAliveInterval 120' -T &
  else
    echo "SSH tunnel to $RIP:$RPORT is up."
  fi
  sleep 60 #sleep 1 minute
done
echo "exiting."
exit 0

The issue that I am facing is the output that I am getting from the script, and that is this:
connect_to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: failed.
At the same time I get the message that the SSH tunnel is up. I wonder why is this, and does it mean that my script is not working as intended? Am I doing something wrong? This is running on Debian (Raspbian).
My second question is how can I test whether the tunnel is working as expected? I understand that the connection can be in different states, and it seems to me that connection can be established, but tunnel not open(sort of connection hangs)? Does nc -z test the connection through the tunnel itself, and can it do that?
Thanks!

Regarding "My second question is ..." - just ask 1 question at a time. If you have a second question then ask it as a different, separate question. See [ask].

Where does the  connect_to failed message come from? Have you tried testing nc manually? You sure you're not making a presumption on its exit code?

I don't know if this will solve your problem or not but let's start by fixing the shebang (see Why is #!/usr/bin/env bash superior to #!/bin/bash?), upper case variables (see Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization), quoting (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), use of a variable instead of a function for the nc code (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), saving/testing the nc exit status instead of just testing the result directly, negative logic, use of <usr>, status messages going to stdout instead of stderr, and removing the unnecessary exit 0:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
rip='A.B.C.D'
rport=8000
raddr="$rip:$rport"
laddr='127.0.0.1:8000'
rusr='<usr>'     # I assume <usr> isn't REALLY in your code

chk_conn() { nc -z "$rip" "$rport"; }

while true
do
  if chk_conn; then
    echo "SSH tunnel to $raddr is up." >&2
  else
    echo "No SSH tunnel to $raddr. Starting..." >&2
    ssh -N -R "$raddr:$laddr" "$rusr@$rip" -i '/path/to/key' -o 'BatchMode yes' -o 'ServerAliveInterval 120' -T &
  fi
  sleep 60 #sleep 1 minute
done
echo "exiting." >&2

YMMV with what the shell thinks <usr> means (it's input and output redirection), hopefully you don't REALLY have that in your code.
If the above doesn't solve your problem then use it anyway as it solves others but then change ssh to ssh -vvv and see if the information that outputs helps you debug your problem.

thanks for the tips, I'll definitely incorporate them going forward. However, these do not solve my problem. The output of nc command is 0 or 1 (looking at the $? variable). However, when I run the same command directly from the prompt I don't get any output. I tried nc -z IP PORT  2>&1, and no output which I get when I run it from a script. That's what's my question about. Is nc doing something else than just checking existing service on remote IP, or is it going deeper which I don't know (does it see the remote IP service or the service on the other side of the tunnel)?

You seem to be mixing up "output" and "exit status". If I define a function foo() { echo hello; return 7; } the output of that function is hello and the exit status is 7. So which is the 0 that you said nc "outputs" - is it really the output that you expect to be 0 (which I could capture with var=$(foo) or is it the exit status that's 0 (which I could capture with foo(); var="$?")? It sounds like you're saying when you run nc -z IP PORT 2>&1; echo "$?" on the command line you get nothing printed on your screen which is impossible unless you're redirecting stdout somewhere.

:) that kind of was the point. the entire script is relying on exit status. However, when I look at my terminal when script is running I saw output that I mentioned in my question. I don't know where that output comes from, because it appeared depending whether service on the other side of the tunnel existed or not. I expect from nc -z to give me status of service on remote IP. As it seems, I cannot reproduce this output anymore after rebooting my device.
